# TemplateBinding ComboBox Background

Tags: wpf, xaml

I would like to change the Background color of a Combobox Style

This will work and change the Background to Red:

```
<Window.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="ComboBoxTest2" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">

            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ComboBox">
                        <Grid>
                            <ToggleButton Grid.Column="2" 
                                          Focusable="false" 
                                          IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsDropDownOpen,Mode=TwoWay,RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" >
                                <ToggleButton.Template>
                                    <ControlTemplate>
                                        <Grid>
                                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="5*" />
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                            <Border x:Name="Border"  Grid.ColumnSpan="2" CornerRadius="5" Background="Red" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" />
                                            <Border x:Name="ContentBorder" Grid.Column="0" CornerRadius="5,0,0,5"  Margin="1"  Background="Red"  BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="0,0,1,0" />
                                            <Path x:Name="Arrow" Grid.Column="1"  Fill="Orange" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Data="M 0 0 L 4 4 L 8 0 Z"/>
                                        </Grid>
                                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                            <Trigger Property="ToggleButton.IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                                                <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="Green" />
                                                <Setter TargetName="ContentBorder" Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
                                            </Trigger>
                                            <Trigger Property="ToggleButton.IsChecked" Value="true">
                                                <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="Green" />
                                            </Trigger>
                                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                </ToggleButton.Template>
                            </ToggleButton>
                            <ContentPresenter Name="ContentSite" IsHitTestVisible="False"  Content="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItem}" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItemTemplate}" ContentTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding ItemTemplateSelector}" Margin="3"  />
                            <TextBox x:Name="PART_EditableTextBox" Visibility="Hidden" IsReadOnly="{TemplateBinding IsReadOnly}"/>
                            <Popup Name="Popup" Placement="Bottom" IsOpen="{TemplateBinding IsDropDownOpen}" AllowsTransparency="True"  Focusable="False" PopupAnimation="Slide">
                                <Grid  Name="DropDown" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" MinWidth="{TemplateBinding ActualWidth}" MaxHeight="{TemplateBinding MaxDropDownHeight}">
                                    <Border x:Name="DropDownBorder" Background="Blue" />
                                    <ScrollViewer SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                                        <StackPanel IsItemsHost="True" />
                                    </ScrollViewer>
                                </Grid>
                            </Popup>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Style.Triggers>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
```

However I would like to change this using TemplateBinding:

```
<Window.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="ComboBoxTest2" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ComboBox">
                        <Grid>
                            <ToggleButton Grid.Column="2" 
                                          Focusable="false" 
                                          IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsDropDownOpen,Mode=TwoWay,RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" >
                                <ToggleButton.Template>
                                    <ControlTemplate>
                                        <Grid>
                                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="5*" />
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                            <Border x:Name="Border"  Grid.ColumnSpan="2" CornerRadius="5" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" />
                                            <Border x:Name="ContentBorder" Grid.Column="0" CornerRadius="5,0,0,5"  Margin="1"  Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"  BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="0,0,1,0" />
                                            <Path x:Name="Arrow" Grid.Column="1"  Fill="Orange" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Data="M 0 0 L 4 4 L 8 0 Z"/>
                                        </Grid>
                                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                            <Trigger Property="ToggleButton.IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                                                <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="Green" />
                                                <Setter TargetName="ContentBorder" Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
                                            </Trigger>
                                            <Trigger Property="ToggleButton.IsChecked" Value="true">
                                                <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="Green" />
                                            </Trigger>
                                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                </ToggleButton.Template>
                            </ToggleButton>
                            <ContentPresenter Name="ContentSite" IsHitTestVisible="False"  Content="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItem}" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItemTemplate}" ContentTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding ItemTemplateSelector}" Margin="3"  />
                            <TextBox x:Name="PART_EditableTextBox" Visibility="Hidden" IsReadOnly="{TemplateBinding IsReadOnly}"/>
                            <Popup Name="Popup" Placement="Bottom" IsOpen="{TemplateBinding IsDropDownOpen}" AllowsTransparency="True"  Focusable="False" PopupAnimation="Slide">
                                <Grid  Name="DropDown" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" MinWidth="{TemplateBinding ActualWidth}" MaxHeight="{TemplateBinding MaxDropDownHeight}">
                                    <Border x:Name="DropDownBorder" Background="Blue" />
                                    <ScrollViewer SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                                        <StackPanel IsItemsHost="True" />
                                    </ScrollViewer>
                                </Grid>
                            </Popup>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Style.Triggers>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
```

This will not change the Background color, it will be completly ignored. I would like to achieve this because I think it would be better code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Background in ToggleButton template is not ignored. It binds to ToggleButton.Background (which is not set), not to ComboBox.Background. There are two Templates, there need to be two Template bindings:

```
<ToggleButton Grid.Column="2" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" ...
```